# Approval required for all comments apart from on the forum

Tags: 6, users, comments, nodes

We need to allow all forum comments to be published automatically, however any comments to articles or any other content type will require approval before being published.

Unfortunately Drupal seems to only have a single permission "post comments without approval" which applies to both the general comments for nodes and also the comments for the forum topic (yes I know they are still nodes)

Is there any easy way round this? I was thinking maybe a rule but it seems a little over the top, surely this must be a common complaint but my searches didnt bring back anything helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is the reason advance forum modules recommends installing [nodecomment](http://www.drupal.org/project/nodecomment).   You can select which content type's comments to be nodes.  Select Form topics.   In nodecomment content type select uncheck publish from the publish options.   Now every comment publish will be unpublish by default